# format cells based on value in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 text files and read their content into 2 arrays using php. Then I create a table and display it on my site. I now want to color every cell from array 2 (column 2) based on certain values.

For Example:

> if a value from array2 contains "busy", it shall be formatted red, if
> it contains "available", it shall be formatted green.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" class="formbody">
        <div class="codetable">
        <?php
            $file1 = "c:/presencetool/ramfile1.txt";
            $file2 = "c:/presencetool/ramfile2.txt";
            $line1= file($file1, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            $line2 = file($file2, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            $combine = array_combine($line1, $line2);   
            $html = "<table align=center>";
            $html .= "<tr><td width=300px></td><td></td></tr>";
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($combine as $file1 =>  $file2):
                $html .= "<tr>";
                $html .= "<td>".$file1."</td>";
                $html .= "<td>".$file2."</td>";
                $html .= "</tr>";
                $i++;
            endforeach;
            $html .= "</table>";
            echo $html;
        ?>
        <div class="codelabel"> 
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried some possible solutions but could not bring it to work.
Any ideas? If there is any Information I should provide, just ask.

edit:
content of ramfile 1&2:

ramfile1:

> User@1
>
> User@2
>
> User@3
>
> ...
>
> User@n

ramfile2:

> Busy
>
> Busy
>
> Available
>
> Busy
>
> ...

Comment: What is the contents of ramfile1.txt and ramfile2.txt files?

Comment: which variable contains `busy` or `available` here ?

Comment: @OnurKAYA I edited the question, the content of the files are usernames and status values on each line

Comment: @GeorgeBailey ramfile2 has line with eiter "Busy" or "Available". I read it out to array 2. So the answer of your question would be every value in array2 is wether `busy` or `availabe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'demo'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$file1 = $path.'ramfile1.txt';
$file2 = $path.'ramfile2.txt';

if(file_exists($file1) && file_exists($file2)) {
    $line1= file($file1, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $line2 = file($file2, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $combine = array_combine($line1, $line2);

    $html = '<table align="center">';
    $html .= '<tr><td width="300px"></td><td></td></tr>';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($combine as $key => $value):
        $html .= '<tr class="'.$value.'">';
        $html .= '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        $html .= '</tr>';
        $i++;
    endforeach;
    $html .= '</table>';
    echo $html;
}
?>
<style>
    .Busy { background-color: #f2a179;}
    .Available { background-color: #00ff00;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, that made exactly what I wanted. Is there any possible way I can only color the cell of column2? So that any cells with "Busy" or "Available" appear colored?

Comment: Yes, you can give the class name on cell. Like this; <td class=“Busy”>demo</td>

Answer (score 0):

> foreach ($combine as $file1 =>  $file2):

This line makes no sense at all. It will probably run but it won't do what you describe. I think you really want something like....

```
foreach ($file1 as $i=>$value) {
            $html .= "<tr>";
            $html .= "<td>".$file1[$i]."</td>";
            $html .= "<td>".$file2[$i]."</td>";
            $html .= "</tr>";
}
```

But that you are resolving data in one file from another based on the line number is a very bad choice of data structure.

> if a value from array2 contains "busy", it shall be formatted red, if it contains "available", it shall be formatted green.

There are lots of ways to do this. You could call a function....

```
$bgcolor=lookup_css_class($file2[$i]);
$html .= "<td class='$bgcolor'>$file2[$i]</td>";
```

Or you could use dependancy injection, or you could use an array lookup. Alternatively you could simply declare CSS classes based on the value and inject the value as the class name for the TD (but bear in mind this allows someone with control over the data to inject html/javascript into your page:

```
td.busy {background-color: red;}
td.free {background-color: green;}

...
    $html .= "<td class='$file2[$i]'>$file2[$i]</td>";
```

Comment: I tried implementing your solution to my code, but something went wrong. I think it's a misplacement from my side. Where exactly do I put your `foreach` and what do I need to remove?